# Filter/Find Element which .eq() two different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to filter a Table row which has in one column one value and in another column a different value. So the logic is, if one row of the column has value1 and value2, then hide all other rows. And if none have value1 and value2 hide all.

The following is what I already tried with jquery

```
var firstDropVal = $('#first .fstselected').text(); //first DropDown Value
var secondDropVal = $('#second .fstselected').text(); // second DropDown Value

// .rows is the class of my table tr
var $rowsNo = $('.rows').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).find('td:visible').eq(0 && 1).text()) !== firstDropVal && secondDropVal
}).hide();
```

HTML Code of my Table

````
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$i++;


 echo "


<tr class='rows' id='rows".$i."'>

<td name='rows".$i."' id='hersteller".$i."' class='text-left'>".$row['Hersteller']."</td>
<td id='artikel".$i."' class='text-left'>".$row['Artikel']."</td>
<td id='mase".$i."' class='text-left'>".$row['Mase']."</td>
<td id='stuecke".$i."' class='text-left'>".$row['Stuecke']."</td>
<td id='herstellerkurz".$i."' class='text-left'>".$row['HerstellerKurz']."</td>
<td id='masekurz".$i."' class='text-left'>".$row['MaseKurz']."</td>
<td id='farbekurz".$i."' class='text-left'>".$row['FarbeKurz']."</td>
<td id='artikelnummer".$i."' class='text-left'>".$row['Artikelnummer']."</td>


</tr>

 "; ```
````

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: @Eddie I posted my Table now

Comment: I added an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the sample simplier, I created a table with only 2 cols. You can `hide()` all rows and `filter()` based on dropdown

```js
$(".filter").change(function() {
  var color = $("#filter-color").val().trim();
  var number = $("#filter-number").val().trim();

  $(".row").hide().filter(function() {
    return (
      color === "" ||
      color === $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().trim()
    ) && (
      number === "" ||
      number === $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().trim()
    )
  }).show();

});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, tr {
  border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
FILTER:

<select id="filter-color" class="filter">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>

<select id="filter-number" class="filter">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<hr />

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>red</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>green</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>red</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>green</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Another option is using `every()` to check the array

```js
$(".filter").change(function() {

  var filters = [                    //Put the filter values in an array. Make sure it is in order of the <td>
    $("#filter-color").val().trim(),
    $("#filter-number").val().trim()
  ];

  $(".row").hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("td").get().every(function(o, i) {
      return $(o).text().trim() === filters[i] || filters[i] == "";
    });
  }).show();

});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
FILTER:

<select id="filter-color" class="filter">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>

<select id="filter-number" class="filter">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<hr />

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>red</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>green</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>red</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>green</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you thats what i needed !

Comment: Happy to hear. Please accept my answer by clicking the check on the left if this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

These don't work the way you're trying to use them

```
.eq(0 && 1)
firstDropVal && secondDropVal
```

due to operator precedence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

you need 4 separate tests (there are other ways, but that's essentially what you're doing)

```
return 
    $.trim($(this).find('td:visible').eq(0).text()) === firstDropVal
    || $.trim($(this).find('td:visible').eq(1).text()) === secondDropVal
    || $.trim($(this).find('td:visible').eq(0).text()) === firstDropVal
    || $.trim($(this).find('td:visible').eq(1).text()) === secondDropVal
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer am gonna try it out now

Comment: TBH not quite clear what you're trying to do - so you may need to switch the logic around (maybe wrap the above with `return !(...)`) or you may not want to use filter at all.  Looks like a typical table search/filter so should be ok.

Comment: I think it could also be `return 
    $.trim($(this).find('td:visible').eq(0).text()) !== firstDropVal
    && $.trim($(this).find('td:visible').eq(1).text()) !== secondDropVal` but as @freedomn-m suggested it isn't clear

Comment: Well since 2 days i am just trying to figure out how i can use multiple dropdowns to filter a table. TBH thats all i am trying to do and i tried out many many different methods and still couldn't figure out how to simply filter a table with multiple dropdowns.  If you see the picture you should know what i mean. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvWJY.png